# Cocos2d -- Check if place is free before moving (all objects)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

Is there a method in Cocos2d like `CGRectIntersectsRect`, except instead of limiting it to one sprite, it checks for ALL objects?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is get all the children in the current layer and then iterate through then and use the `CGRectIntersectsRect` function to check if the any node is present at your desired location.

After that you can do what ever you want to do with the nodes that are present at that frame.

You need to get all the nodes like this

```
CCArray *childrenNodes = [self children];
```

and check for intersection like this

```
for(CCNode *someNode in childrenNodes)
{
    CGRect rect = ((CCSprite *)someNode).textureRect;
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, desiredRect))
    {
        // --------------------->Do something
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
As mentioned in your below comment you can modify the above code to only check for a particular type of sprite or sprites. For this to happen you need to subclass ccsprite or give a tag to a set of sprite representing a particular type of object, then in the for loop only check for that sprite or sprites depending on your requirement.

```
for(CCNode *someNode in childrenNodes)
{
    if([someNode isKindOfClass:YourSpriteClass] || someNode.tag == 81)
        continue;
    CGRect rect = ((CCSprite *)someNode).textureRect;
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, desiredRect))
    {
        // --------------------->Do something
    }
}
```

I think you will get the idea from the above code.

Comment: But what about the other children in the room? What if I just wanted it to be for one type of object, like a wall, but not, say, a tree?

Comment: hey @JackStone Did you try out the code with the changes that i made in my answer.